# hadoop connection refused from external request

Tags: hadoop, firewall

I have beeing fighting with this issue for quite a while and can not find out solution, hope you can help me.
I created a new centos7 VM, installed hadoop, now, I can easily run

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://hadoop-vm:8020/
```

to list all the file.
But from external VM or my local Mac, if use same command, I got connection refused error:

```
Call From xxxx/172.21.162.71 to hadoop-vm:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

1. I disabled firewall in hadoopVM:

   systemctl status firewalld
   firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: inactive (dead)
2. I have set Selinux = disabled already

And still always failed, can not access hdfs from external client. Can anyone help to figure out how to make hadoop accessible from external client?

Comment: Try a telnet <server> <port> to see if the port is accessible remotely at all.

Comment: Not accessible at all. In hadoop VM, I can use "telnet localhost 8020", but in my local "telnet hadoop-vm 8020" is NOT working at all. "ping hadoop-vm" is working fine, so host name to ip is correctly mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the reason, I have to put real ip in core-site.xml, originally, I was using hdfs://localhost:9000 or hdfs://hadoop-vm:9000, none is working, only accepting local request, but once I changed it to hdfs://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9000, hadoop can accept remote requests. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank! I wasted an entire day until I found this post. Same problem solved.